# set default value for forms from state in ant design form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, antd, react-typescript

I have two components : **1.** `App.tsx` which I define my state with initial value for min and max input. **2.** `Form.tsx` which my inputs are here.([I'm using ant design form](https://ant.design/components/form/) )

**Question**: how can I pass default value for min and max which define in state(`min: 1,max: 4,`) in `App.tsx` to `Form.tsx` component?(I put ? in defaultValue `defaultValue={?}`)

Here is summary of my code:

App.tsx:

```
type IProps={
  min:number;
  max:number
}

 const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState<Iprops>({
    min: 1,
    max: 4,
  });

return (
<div>
<Form />
</div>
```

Form.tsx:

```
              <Row>
                <Col span={12}>
                  <Form.Item
                    name="min"
                    label="Min"
                  >
                    <InputNumber
                      min={1}
                      max={10}
                      defaultValue={?}
                      size="small"
                    />
                  </Form.Item>
                </Col>
                <Col span={12}>
                  <Form.Item
                    name="max"
                    label="Max (10000 node)"
                  >
                    <InputNumber
                      min={1}
                      max={10000}
                      defaultValue={?}
                    />
                  </Form.Item>
                </Col>
              </Row>
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use props pass to the  component.
Maybe you can try this way:

```js
 const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState<Iprops>({
    min: 1,
    max: 4,
  });

return <div>
    <Form minDefaultValue={formValues.min} maxDefaultValue={formValues.max} />
  </div>;
  
 // use props in the form component
 <InputNumber 
    min={1}
    max={10000}
    defaultValue={props.minDefaultValue}
/>

<InputNumber
  min={1}
  max={10000}
  defaultValue={props.maxDefaultValue}
/>
```